# Passing vector iterator to a function c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Can anyone explain to me why the following segment compiles but the commented line after doesn't?

```
struct tObj
{
    int data;
    int moreData;
}

...

void funcToCall (tObj *obj, int moreData)
{
    //Useful stuff here
}

void mainFunction ()
{
    vector<tObj>::iterator it = vectorOfObjects.begin(); //assumes vectorOfObjects is already defined
    while (it != vectorOfObjects.end())
    {
        funcToCall (&(*it), 0); //This line works
        funcToCall (it, 0); //This line produces an error
        it++;
    }
}
```

The error produced is this:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<tObj>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<tObj*, std::vector<tObj> >}’ to ‘tObj*’
```

Any ideas on why `&(*it)` works but just plain `it` doesn't? Logically they are the same, aren't they?

Because doesn't `*` mean to dereference and `&` mean pass by reference aka cancelling each other out?

Comment: The function expects a pointer to `tObj`, you pass an iterator. An iterator is not a pointer (although some implementations *might* implement `vector<T>::iterator` as `T*`.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`it` is an iterator object, passing it as-is would mean you're trying to pass an object of type `vector<tObj>::iterator` for a function expecting `tObj*`, and thus the error.

When you do `*it` you'd get the underlying object the iterator is representing and when you apply `&` atop that, you get *that* object's address, which is of type `tObj*` which agrees with the function's argument type and thus no error.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip. I guess vector iterators are just confusing to me.

Comment: Perhaps, but just think of iterators as just that - not pointers, not anything else. They just allow you to iterate over a collection in some fashion. And these iterators provide an `operator*` to access the underlying element and it's got nothing to do with pointers; it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: That's makes a lot more sense. Thanks heaps for that info. Never even crossed my mind that they could of been overloading `operator*` .

Answer (score 7):

That the code would be compiled you have to declare an overloaded function like

```
void funcToCall ( std::vector<tObj>::iterator it, int moreData)
{
    //Useful stuff here
}
```

In general case types `tObj *` and `vector<tObj>::iterator` are different types though in some old realizations of std::vector its iterator is indeed defined as a pointer..